# how to replace the tabs with empty space in each file of a directory

Tags: sed

I would like to replace the tabs in each file of a directory with the **corresponding** empty space. I found already a solution 11094383, where you can replace tabs with **given** number of empty spaces:

```
> find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\t/     /g' {} \;
```

In the solution above tabs are replaced with four spaces. But in my case tabs can occupy more spaces - e.g. 8.

An example of file with tabs, which should be replaced with 8 spaces is:

```
NSMl1        100  PSHELL 0.00260  400000  400200  400300
          400400  400500  400600  400700  400800  400900
      401000  401100  400100  430000  430200  430300
      430400  430500  430600  430700  430800  430900
      431000  431100  430100  401200  431200
```

here the lines with tabs are the 3th to the 5th line.

An example of file with tabs, which should be replaced with 4 tabs is:

```
RBE2     1101001 5000511  123456    1100
```

Could anybody help?

Comment: did you want to replace tabs with 6 or 8 spaces?

Comment: in my case I have to replace tabs with 4, 6 or 8 spaces

Comment: You're looking for `expand`: http://man.cx/expand

Comment: it would replace tabs with 8 spaces. `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\t/\s\{8\}/g' {} \;`

Comment: it is important to preserve the position of the letters. I have some tabs which have to be replaced with 4 or with 8 spaces.

Comment: @glennjackman well in expand one have to define the spaces too if I am not wrong?

Comment: Could you provide examples for the different cases (i.e. explaining when you want to replace a tab with 4 spaces, or 6 spaces, or 8 spaces)?

Comment: @Drago, I linked to a man page. The only thing you need to specify is the custom tab stops if the default doesn't suit you.

Comment: Please provide some sample input for us to play with.

Comment: Why if you know what files need 8 spaces already dont you modify the statement to have 8 spaces `find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\t/        /g' {} \;` (it does not show on the comment but i put 8 spaces in the substitution.. (@AvinashRaj that syntax does not work in my sed)

Answer (score 1):

The classic answer is to use the `pr` command with options to expand tabs into an appropriate number of spaces, turning of the pagination features:

```
pr -e8 -l1 -t …files…
```

The tricky part is getting the file over-written that seems to be part of the question.  Of course, `sed` in the GNU and BSD (Mac OS X) incarnations supports overwriting with the `-i` option — with variant behaviours between the two as BSD `sed` requires a suffix for the backup files and GNU `sed` does not.  However, `sed` does not (readily) support converting tabs to an appropriate number of blanks, so it isn't wholly appropriate.

There's a script `overwrite` (which I abbreviate to `ow`) in [The UNIX Programming Environment](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013937681X) that can do that.  I've been using the script since 1987 (first checkin — last updated in 2005).

```
#!/bin/sh
#       Overwrite file
#       From: The UNIX Programming Environment by Kernighan and Pike
#       Amended: remove PATH setting; handle file names with blanks.

case $# in
0|1)    echo "Usage: $0 file command [arguments]" 1>&2
        exit 1;;
esac

file="$1"
shift
new=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/ovrwr.$$.1
old=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/ovrwr.$$.2

trap "rm -f '$new' '$old' ; exit 1" 0 1 2 15

if "$@" >"$new"
then
    cp "$file" "$old"
    trap "" 1 2 15
    cp "$new" "$file"
    rm -f "$new" "$old"
    trap 0
    exit 0
else
    echo "$0: $1 failed - $file unchanged" 1>&2
    rm -f "$new" "$old"
    trap 0
    exit 1
fi
```

It would be possible and arguably better to use the `mktemp` command on most systems these days; it didn't exist way back then.

In the context of the question, you could then use:

```
find . -type f -exec ow {} pr -e8 -t -l1 \;
```

You do need to process each file separately.

If you are truly determined to use `sed` for the job, then you have your work cut out.  There's a gruesome way to do it.  There is a notational problem; how to represent a literal tab; I will use `\t` to denote it.  The script would be stored in a file, which I'll assume is `script.sed`:

```
:again
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\t/s//\1        /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{1\}\)\t/s//\1\3       /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{2\}\)\t/s//\1\3      /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{3\}\)\t/s//\1\3     /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{4\}\)\t/s//\1\3    /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{5\}\)\t/s//\1\3   /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{6\}\)\t/s//\1\3  /
/^\(\([^\t]\{8\}\)*\)\([^\t]\{7\}\)\t/s//\1\3 /
t again
```

That's using the classic `sed` notation.

You can then write:

```
sed -f script.sed …data-files…
```

If you have GNU `sed` or BSD (Mac OS X) `sed`, you can use the extended regular expressions instead:

```
:again
/^(([^\t]{8})*)\t/s//\1        /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{1})\t/s//\1\3       /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{2})\t/s//\1\3      /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{3})\t/s//\1\3     /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{4})\t/s//\1\3    /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{5})\t/s//\1\3   /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{6})\t/s//\1\3  /
/^(([^\t]{8})*)([^\t]{7})\t/s//\1\3 /
t again
```

and then run:

```
sed -r -f script.sed …data-files…    # GNU sed
sed -E -f script.sed …data-files…    # BSD sed
```

What do the scripts do?

The first line sets a label; the last line jumps to that label if any of the `s///` operations in between made a substitution.  So, for each line of the file, the script loops until there are no matches made, and hence no substitutions performed.

The 8 substitutions deal with:

- A block of zero or more sequences of 8 non-tabs, which is captured, followed by
- a sequence of 0-7 more non-tabs, which is also captured, followed by
- a tab.
- It replaces that match with the captured material, followed by an appropriate number of spaces.

One curiosity found during the testing is that if a line ends with white space, the `pr` command removes that trailing white space.

There's also the `expand` command on some systems (BSD or Mac OS X at least), which preserves the trailing white space.  Using that is simpler than `pr` or `sed`.

With these `sed` scripts, and using the BSD or GNU `sed` with backup files, you can write:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i.bak -r -f script.sed {} +
```

(GNU `sed` notation; substitute `-E` for `-r` for BSD `sed`.)